# Azure DevOps Template not working (Unexpected values)

Tags: templates, azure-devops, yaml

I want to include a template, but it won't work. I know this is somehow a duplicate question, but the other answers don't solve my problem.

**Template-File (base.yml)**

```
trigger:
- master

pool: 'Etiscan Windows'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'x86'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '76b8ae4e-2263-4849-bfb3-e1f621bf5bd7'
...to be continued....
```

**Azure-Pipelines.yml**

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: YML-Templates/NugetCfBuilderTemplate
stages:
 - stage: Job1
 - template: base.yml@templates
```

**Errors**

> /base.yml@templates (Line: 6, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'trigger'
> /base.yml@templates (Line: 9, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'pool'
> /base.yml@templates (Line: 11, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'variables'
> /base.yml@templates (Line: 16, Col: 1): Unexpected value 'steps'

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the resource, we can also add the trigger, refer [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#resources-repositories). Help you modified the yaml, hope this will help:

```
resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: templates
    type: git
    name: YML-Templates/NugetCfBuilderTemplate
    trigger: 
      branches:
        include:
          - master
stages:
 - stage: Job1
 - template: base.yml@templates
```

Note: please remove the trigger in your base.yml file.

**Update:**
I help you modified your base yaml and here I use the Powershell task to do the test:

```
stages:
  - stage: job1
    pool: 'default' 
    variables:
      solution: '**/*.sln'
      buildPlatform: 'x86'
      buildConfiguration: 'Release'
    jobs:
      - job: A1
        steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # Write your PowerShell commands here.
              
              Write-Host "Hello World"
#       - task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
        # - task: NuGetCommand@2
        #   inputs:
        #     command: 'restore'
        #     restoreSolution: '**/*.sln'
        #     feedsToUse: 'select'
        #     vstsFeed: '76b8ae4e-2263-4849-bfb3-e1f621bf5bd7'
```

**Note:** Please remove the ' - stage: Job1' from your main yaml file.

Comment: Ok, the "trigger" error has gone away. But the errors with "unexpected values" pool, variables, steps are still there.

Comment: Hi @etalon11, I help you modified your demo yaml and I use my 'default' pool to do the test. You can try again with the update yaml. Please don't forget to remove the '- stage: Job1' from your main yaml file. I have help you named the base.yaml as the stage job1

Answer (score 0):

Trigger can be defined only at the pipeline level, you cannot set it at the stage level. The stage can only have these children (see [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema%2Cparameter-schema#stage)):

```yaml
stages:
- stage: string  # name of the stage (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, and underscore)
  displayName: string  # friendly name to display in the UI
  dependsOn: string | [ string ]
  condition: string
  variables: # several syntaxes, see specific section
  jobs: [ job | templateReference]
```

You also need to insert a Job containing the steps and move the pool stanza down to Job level.